# エラーの原因の特定方法がいまいちわかりません。

Tags: cakephp

初心者の質問で大変申し訳ないです。

下記、どなたかご教示頂けますと幸いです。

現在、cakephpで作成したサイトの管理画面に入ろうとすると 
500エラーが表示されてしまいます。

こちら１９日までは入れたのですが、 
２０日の夜からアクセス出来ずに５００エラーになりました。

２０日の作業内容としては、 
var/www/html/サイト名//tmp/log 
を削除致しました。

また、エラーログの内容としては下記が表示されております。

```
2016-07-20 23:46:07 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class SupportedBrowsersController could not be found.

0 /var/www/html/サイト名/webroot/index.php(110): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
```

誠に恐縮ですが、 
私が初心者のため、まだ原因の特定方法がわかりません。

ですので、こちら原因の特定方法をご教示頂けますと幸いです。 
お手数をお掛け致しますが何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `SupportedBrowsersController` というコントローラが見つからない、というエラーですね。例えば、 `/supported_browsers/` 等のURLにアクセスされたが、`app/Controller/SupportedBrowsersController.php` が存在しない、といった場合に出ると思いますが、このファイルは存在していますか？あるいはそんなURL・コントローラに心当たりはないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

まず、エラーで示しているメッセージをキチンと読み下しましょう。
まずエラー5xx番台はサーバ側でエラーのステータスコードを発しています。
自分から発していなければ大体はスクリプトが停止したエラーになります。

次に

```
2016-07-20 23:46:07 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class SupportedBrowsersController could not be found.
```

この内容ですが、
ファイルの読み込みなどで存在しないパスに接続されたりすると発生する場合があります。
ログファイルを削除されたようなので、
なにかしらのログを書き込もうとしたが、削除されているため書き込みできなかった。
もしくは読み込もうとしたがファイルが存在しなかった。
推測ですが、そういう可能性があります。

また、後述の停止箇所を示唆している行

```
0 /var/www/html/サイト名/webroot/index.php(110): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
```

上記では、`index.php`の110行目にある
`Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))`
でエラーを起こし停止していると記されています。

接続されたリクエストか何かを`index.php`からログに書き出そうとしているのでは？
どちらにしろですが、ソースコードが無いので何が原因、とハッキリといえないので、
`index.php`のコードを追うしかないんじゃないでしょうか?

ファイルのIOで失敗しているのなら空のログファイルを設置しなおせば動くかもしれませんね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。　　すごく思考方法がわかりやすくご参考にさせていだきます。